# Decode value from URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am taking a parameter value from the URL which is as follows:

```
users%2F3
```

Where it should be users/3

How can I decode the value I am getting using Javascript?

I tried the following before:

```
var a = "users%2F3"; 
console.log(decodeURI(a));
```

But the log shows the same encoded value.

Comment: A normal google search will give you this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

Answer (score 1):

With the imaginatively named [`decodeURIComponent` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent). (See also [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.3.2)).

Comment: I tried that before as follows: var a = "users%2F3"; console.log(decodeURI(a)); and the log shows the same value ...

Comment: @MiguelMoura Yes, a completely different function (`decodeURI`) doesn't do the same thing as `decodeURIComponent`.

Comment: Ah now I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> CODE for decode URL
>        `html code`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to decode a URI after encoding it.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var uri = "users%2F3";
var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri);
var res = "Decoded URI: " + uri_dec;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want you can create your own function like

`function urldecode(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent((str+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
 };`

this will also replace the '+' from the decodeURI component into spaces

Answer (score -2):

you can use

`decodeURIComponent(a)`